# When a browser opens a new tab does it give it some unique identifier?

Tags: browser

When a browser opens a new tab I know that it sets a Title property, however this might be the same as the title for another instance of a tab in the same browser. I assume that the browser must set some sort of unique identifier for each tab that is open in the browser so it knows which one it is working with. My question is "Is there a unique identifier for each tab that I can get access to?"

Edit: I open a database when with a URL of say http:\192.168.0.1\someDB.nsf (this is a IBM Notes/Domino application). From an email sent to the user they get a link say http:\192.168.0.1\someDB.nsf?app=SomeApp so if the client already has the browser open by opening the link directly then clicks the link in the email they open a new tab so that the same Db is open in each tab. This will potentially cause significant problems. So if there is another instance of the database open in another tab I want to either redirect this URL to that has the DB open or block it from opening.

Comment: `<a href="link" target="uniquename">Link</a>` can be accessed as frame name=uniquename.  All links target 'uniquename' will be open in that tab.  If using target="_blank" it will always open a new tab, but I don't know how to get the unique identifier the browser will have given.

Comment: I can set the target in my link which would be good, but is a person opens the DB directly in the web browser is there a way to set the Target name for the tab that it opens in.

Comment: not that I know off.  There use to exist scripts to detect if a page was loaded in a frameset, if not, would redirect to the frameset.  I  guess this technique could be used, testing if frame name 'uniquename' does not exist, then reopen same page threw a frameset (a 0px frame might be necessary, also called frameset redirection)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, perhaps this will help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser